# Color html table based on 3 conditions

Tags: html, css, angular

I have 3 colors defined in CSS. In HTML i have table and I want the backdround color of a cell to change based on 3 conditions:

```
 if cell contains the text 'True'     - color green
 if cell contains the text 'False'    - color red
 if the cell contains the text 'None' - color yellow
```

my css:

```
.color-green {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
  }

  .color-yellow {
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .color-red {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

my html:

```
<td ng-class = "{'color-yellow':dict.status='True','color-red':dict.status=='false'}">{{ dict.status}}</td>
```

I tried with 2 colors first, but this just changes my cells to True with red backround.
I haven't touched html in a long time but i remembered this method worked with numbers.
Tried to google but not so lucky :(

Is there any way of doing what I want with the 3 colors?

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular? Please add the correct tag.

Comment: it's angular. i'll add

Comment: You have `dict.status='True'` and it's not a condition, but assignment - you're setting dict.status to 'True'. Use == and check if you want it to read 'true' or 'True'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional (ternary) operator can use for this goal. More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

The following code is using class and `{{  }}` then using ternary operator. if `dict.status.includes('True')` returns true then class is equal to `color-green` else if `dict.status.includes('False')` returns true then the class is equal to `color-red` and else class becomes `color-yellow`.

```
class = "{{ dict.status.includes('True') ? 'color-green' : dict.status.includes('False') ? 'color-red' : 'color-yellow' }}
```

```css
.color-green {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
  }

  .color-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .color-red {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
    Type your text in this box: 
    <input type="text" ng-model="dict.status">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class = "{{ dict.status.includes('True') ? 'color-green' : dict.status.includes('False') ? 'color-red' : 'color-yellow' }}">{{ dict.status}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can try with the directive [ngClass] :

```
<td [ngClass] = "{'color-yellow':dict.status='true','color-red':dict.status=='false'}">{{ dict.status}}</td>
```

Where you can assign class to an element using it.

[Playground link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-vpcqoh?file=app%2Fhello-framework%2Fhello-framework.component.html)